# Core Data cascade on Data Inserts

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite

I'm currently learning to use Core Data on iOS , in my test application I have two entities with an inverse relation, the delete cascade is working fine but i wonder if it is possible to have a update or insert cascade as well? for example if I create a new instance of entity 1 i want some of its attributes to be copied onto a new object of entity 2.

Do I have to write some code for this or is there some built in solution?
searching the internet gave me no results.

(also since I'm new to Core Data i'm thinking in terms of tables as my persistent store is of SQLite so an insert into one table must essentially copy a few attributes into another table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think of it in a different way.  If those two objects share those properties, perhaps it would be best to create another entity who contains those fields and entity 1 and entity 2 would both have a common relationship to.  Having multiple copies of the same data just doesn't seem like a good idea where it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

(You haven't mentioned multiplicity of the relationship, which could be important.)
Not sure if this directly addresses your question, but …

If you have `A <--> B`.  (1-to-1 relationship)

Cascade rules:
 `A cascades: B`
 `B nils: A`

(this is an A "owns" B description)

(above A/B == entities, below A/B == instances of entities)

if `A(1) -> B(2)`

and then you set

`A(3) -> B(2)`

B(2)'s reverse relationship to A(1) is nil'd out before it's set to A(3)
A(1) is left with a nil value (if that's not valid in the data model description, you're now in trouble, otherwise, it's B-less)

`A(1) -> <nil>`